# ¿Es mejor validar el formulario desde JS y enviarlo a PHP o validarlo en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero saber si esta bien validar el formulario desde JS primero para saber que los datos ingresados sean los correctos, si no, no enviar dicha petición; es decir, que sea solo string, números, etc, ya en PHP limpiar las variables y hacer lo que tenga que hacer con ellas. ¿Está bien así o  se tiene que validar desde PHP?

Comment: Siempre es mejor en ambos labos

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo que es probable que sea cerrada. Aún así me tomo la libertad de expresar la mía :) yo prefiero hacer la validación en ambos sitios. Desde javascript para facilitar al usuario la tarea de rellenar los campos antes de su envío real, y en PHP porque es importante mantener la validación de los campos en PHP para evitar que se reciban datos incorrectos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a tratar de responderte con hechos, aunque la pregunta se preste a opiniones y le quede un telediario para que la cierren:

Si **validas los datos en el frontend**, evitas mandar peticiones innecesarias al backend. Por ejemplo, si tienes un formulario con un campo de email del usuario y el usuario lo escribe mal y envía el formulario, el backend va a recibir ese email incorrecto, validarlo, devolver respuesta de error, etc. Muchos pasos, código ejecutado y comunicaciones que se podrían evitar si lo validas mediante JavaScript, que encima es código que ejecuta la máquina usuario, por lo que descarga de trabajo a nuestro backend.

Además, validar en el frontend tiene ventajas de usabilidad, ya que puedes darle feedback al usuario de forma inmediata de que el campo que está escribiendo no es válido.

Respecto a la **validación en el backend**: no se puede asumir que si ya tienes validaciones en el frontend no vas a necesitar validaciones en el backend. Se puede forjar un formulario que envíe datos no válidos a tu endpoint. Siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior, si tienes una validación en JavaScript que mira si un email es correcto y luego no haces esa misma validación en el backend, una persona podría crearse un formulario que mandase al backend un email sin arroba, tu validación de JavaScript no entraría en juego y tu backend se zamparía ese email inválido, lo que luego podría generar problemas en otros puntos de la aplicación; por ejemplo si tratases de enviar un email a esa dirección sin arroba.

También hay que indicar, que hay cierto tipo de validaciones que hay que hacer necesariamente en el backend.

Comment: Mi +1, aunque cambiaría o mejoraría el párrafo final ya que no solo se debe validar siempre "si una contraseña es correcta", si no que se debe validar que la sesión de usuario es correcta y que el usuario que ha iniciado sesión tiene realmente permisos para hacer lo que está a punto de hacer. Es decir, si tiene permisos para editar los datos de algo o enviar la notificación en nombre de quien ha puesto como remitente, por poner ejemplos.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, si, la verdad es que no me he explicado muy bien al final, ya lo he editado

Comment: Haz escrito en palabras justo aquello que yo hubiese escrito,  ahi va mi +1.

Comment: eso no es del todo correcto. La parte segura que tiene que hacer el backend es validar que la contraseña es segura. Existen mas metodos para validar la sesion (tokens, aplicaciones de infraestructura como kong...) lo especifico del backend es la conexion hacia bbdd. (Aunque esto tambien depende de la arquitectura de tu aplicacion)

Comment: Esto es un excelente resumen de seguridad.